# Allow Wordpress Plugin Input Field to Output HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, module, escaping

I'm using a multipurpose theme which has many out of the box modules like buttons, CTAs and etc. The problem is that for an instance I want to add  tag to the button's text field:

[image]

Which renders that on my site:
[image]

I've always wondered if there's a way to modify the module's php to allow HTML and not escape it? I've tried using wp_kses and many other functions I've googled, but nothing seems to help. Here's the code from the button.php which is relevant in my opinion:

```
    function render( $attrs, $content = null, $render_slug ) {
    $button_url        = $this->props['button_url'];
    $button_rel        = $this->props['button_rel'];
    $button_text       = $this->props['button_text'];
    $background_layout = $this->props['background_layout'];
    $url_new_window    = $this->props['url_new_window'];
    $custom_icon       = $this->props['button_icon'];
    $button_custom     = $this->props['custom_button'];
    $button_alignment  = $this->get_button_alignment();

    // Nothing to output if neither Button Text nor Button URL defined
    $button_url = trim( $button_url );

    if ( '' === $button_text && '' === $button_url ) {
        return '';
    }

    // Module classnames
    $this->add_classname( "et_pb_bg_layout_{$background_layout}" );

    // Render Button
    $button = $this->render_button( array(
        'button_id'        => $this->module_id( false ),
        'button_classname' => explode( ' ', $this->module_classname( $render_slug ) ),
        'button_custom'    => $button_custom,
        'button_rel'       => $button_rel,
        'button_text'      => $button_text,
        'button_url'       => $button_url,
        'custom_icon'      => $custom_icon,
        'has_wrapper'      => false,
        'url_new_window'   => $url_new_window,
    ) );

    // Render module output
    $output = sprintf(
        '<div class="et_pb_button_module_wrapper et_pb_module%2$s">
            %1$s
        </div>',
        $button,
        sprintf( ' et_pb_button_alignment_%1$s', esc_attr( $button_alignment ) )
    );

    return $output;
}
```

I guess that these are the lines which are important, how to modify them to make it work:

```
'button_text'      => $button_text,
$button_text       = $this->props['button_text'];
```

Comment: Please share the code of the `render_button` function as well. There's where the button is actually generated.

Comment: Here, it's from different file **class-et-builder-element.php** - https://pastebin.com/asAK70jG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's converting your HTML tags into text:

```
// Render button
return sprintf( '%7$s<a%9$s class="%5$s" href="%1$s"%3$s%4$s%6$s>%2$s</a>%8$s',
    esc_url( $args['button_url'] ),
    esc_html( $args['button_text'] ),
    ( 'on' === $args['url_new_window'] ? ' target="_blank"' : '' ),
    et_esc_previously( $data_icon ),
    esc_attr( implode( ' ', array_unique( $button_classname ) ) ), // #5
    et_esc_previously( $this->get_rel_attributes( $args['button_rel'] ) ),
    $args['has_wrapper'] ? '<div class="et_pb_button_wrapper">' : '',
    $args['has_wrapper'] ? '</div>' : '',
    '' !== $args['button_id'] ? sprintf( ' id="%1$s"', esc_attr( $args['button_id'] ) ) : ''
);
```

`esc_html( $args['button_text'] )` is the culprit. Change it into `$args['button_text']` and you're good to go.

Comment: Works, thank you! I just need to find a way to modify it in my child theme now :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the HTML element? if it's either `button` or `input (type=submit)`, you can't add HTML to that, you'd have to make a custom button with the `a` tag.

Comment: Here's how the output looks:
`<a class="et_pb_button et_pb_module et_pb_button_0 btn btn-info et_pb_bg_layout_light" href="http://google.com">blabla &lt;strong&gt;blabla&lt;/strong&gt;</a>`

So, yeah, it's `a`

Comment: Somewhere in `$this->render_button` it must add something like `htmlspecialchars` to the text..?

Comment: Here's the render_button func from file **class-et-builder-element.php** - https://pastebin.com/asAK70jG

Comment: Yes, so `esc_html` is escaping the content,you'll probably have to create your own button function